# How to fetch all colums in Row for a particular Headings and their values corresponding to some other headings

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

I have one table A:

```
CREATE TABLE A( C NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, C2 NUMBER, C3 NUMBER, C4 NUMBER );

INSERT INTO A ( C, C2, C3, C4 )
SELECT 1, 2, 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 8, 3, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

I am having another table `B` which is having `C` as Foreign Key.
The `B` table does not have all the columns mapped to `A`; it has mapped only some columns like `c2`,`c3`..

Now I want to fetch all the data from both of the table which will include all the columns from `A` based upon the join with `B` in below format.

```
Column_name  Values 
C2            2
C2            8
C3            1
C3            3
C4            4
C4            2
```

Please suggest how can I can use Joins or using pivot for the same.

**Edit:**
`DDL` for table B.

```
CREATE TABLE B( C NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, C2 NUMBER,C3 NUMBER, C8 NUMBER);
INSERT INTO B ( C, C2, C3,C8 ) 
SELECT 1, 2, 1,5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 8, 3 ,9 FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Please add the DDL statements defining table `B` and some sample data for that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
       VALUE_S
FROM
  (SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
          value_s
   FROM a UNPIVOT (value_s
                   FOR COLUMN_NAME IN (c2, c3, c4)) ) a
JOIN b ON SUBSTR(a.COLUMN_NAME,2) = b.c
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME,
         VALUE_S ;
```

**Edit:**
Based on your comment changed to `JOIN b ON SUBSTR(a.COLUMN_NAME,2) = b.c`

Comment: Hi Kaushik, 
Thnx a lot for ur sugestion ,
I tried  to run the same query and its giving the result in the same format but only if I skip the join part.
With the joining its giving error as invalid number.
.
What is the issue with the join???
Both table are mapped to column C w.r.t each other.
The 2nd table(B) I have created is having columns as C(PK),C2,C3,C8 .
Please give ur inputs.

Comment: The DDL/DML for table B is below :

CREATE TABLE B( C NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, C2 NUMBER,C3 NUMBER, C8 NUMBER)

INSERT INTO B ( C, C2, C3,C8 ) 
SELECT 1, 2, 1,5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, 8, 3 ,9 FROM DUAL

Comment: Your column `C` in table `B` is a number and `Column_name` is a character. I have edited the answer.please check .

Comment: Hi Kaushik,

Thanks a  ton ..its working fine.
This query is working only when all columns with the same data type.Now in my tables I am having Diff type of columns it is giving me error.
So in the same query suppose we have to fetch C5,C6 columns as Varchar type and C10 columns as Date type. how  can I do get it ?
please advice.

Comment: @Rishabh : Please ask that as a separate question, giving some  background from this question. It has been modified already a few times here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.C2, B.C2, A.C3, B.C3, A.C4, B.C4 FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.C = B.C
```

the `inner join` on B has to be the foreign key between `table A` and `table B`. So in your case `A.C` & `B.C` can be different.